# How to get the first name of a user logged in through Facebook on ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following api calls to get the info of user logged in via facebook...

First I call this method of FBSDKLoginManager.

```
- (void)logInWithReadPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions
              fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController
                         handler:(FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler)handler;
```

and once the login is successful I call the below method.

```
    NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parameters setValue:@"id,name,email,birthday,gender,education,work" forKey:@"fields"];
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
                          startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id user, NSError *error) {
                              if (!error) {
                                  [[CleverTap push] graphUser:user];
                              }
                          }];
```

My point is that the FBSDK contains a class named FBSDKProfile.
This has some properties which I can use like first name middle name and others. How can I access this..? because even after login the shared instance of this class gives me nil.

```
NSLog(@"name %@", [FBSDKProfile currentProfile].firstName);
```

Am I missing something here..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to user **`first_name`** in your parameter.

See the sample code to get the **first name**.

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                   parameters:@{@"fields": @"first_name"}]
                   startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

         NSString *name;
         if (!error) {
             name = result[@"first_name"];
         }
}];
```

If you want another field, see the list here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

Comment: This works but I was thinking of getting the FBSDKProfile object somehow.. but thanks anyway.